# How do you say "from cover to cover"?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

How can I translate “from cover to cover” in French? This means from the very beginning until the very end.

The typical context of using "from cover to cover" in English would be reading the book, though I want to use it (in French) in the context of watching a movie.

What phrase could I use?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On peut dire *lire un livre de bout en bout*, ou *regarder un film de bout en bout*. On peut aussi dire *du début à la fin*, c'est un peu plus prosaïque. Comme on commence normalement au début, on peut aussi dire *regarder un film jusqu'au bout*.

Answer (score 5):

You can say: *d'un bout à l'autre*.

Answer (score 4):

On top of [Gilles' answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/7390/1129), and only appliable to movies, you could use

> jusqu'à la dernière minute
>
> jusqu'à la dernière seconde
>
> jusqu'à la (toute) fin

Comment: Et au théatre, ne dirions-nous pas "jusqu'au dernier coup"?

Answer (score 4):

Si c'est une corvée et qu'on se sent l'âme dramatique, on peut dire:

> Boire le calice jusqu'à la lie.

Answer (score 2):

Dans un contexte plus familier, surtout à l'oral, on peut aussi utiliser :

> [J'ai lu l'intégrale de cet auteur] de A à Z.

Comment: -1 : Ça ne correspond ni à une traduction possible de *from cover to cover*, ni n'est applicable à un film.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if "*from cover to cover*" can be intended to mean "*in one reading/screening*" (that is, not only reading the whole thing, but also without taking breaks). But if it does, then

> d'une traite

conveys this idea.

You can combine:

> J'ai regardé ce film jusqu'au bout, d'une traite.

Comment: Good thought, but to the best of my knowledge, it doesn't carry that meaning. It's about exhaustiveness. Though it can certainly be combined to clarify a sentence like "I read it from cover to cover in one day" -- that is, "Don't assume I didn't read every page simply because I read it one day!" :)